# ASP net core multipart/forma-data, two files

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, httprequest

I need to read [httppost] request from my video camera which sends image file and son file with License Plate data. This is how the request looks like from camera (user manual):

```
POST /alpv/receive.php HTTP/1.1\r\n  Host: 10.13.24.13\r\n  Content-Length: 7160\r\n  
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------3df4e8eee91da308\r\n    --------------------------3df4e8eee91da308  
Content-Disposition:  form-data;  name="event"; filename="20190204103017_10536event_7000175.json"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream  
{   "packetCounter":"7000175",  
 "datetime":"20190204 103017000",  
 "plateText":"\u004c\u0042\u0045\u0033\u0039\u0037",  
 "plateCountry":"SWE", 
  "plateConfidence":"0.716159",  
 "carState":"new",  
 "geotag":{"lat": 50.418114,"lon": 30.476213},  
 "imageType": "plate", 
  "plateImageType": "png", 
  "plateImageSize":  "0",  
 "carMoveDirection":"in", 
  "timeProcessing":"0",  
 "plateCoordinates":[1614, 880, 172, 28],  
 "carID":"18", 
  "GEOtarget":"Camera", 
  "sensorProviderID":"defaultID"  }  
--------------------------3df4e8eee91da308  
Content-Disposition:  form-data;  name="image";  filename="20190204103016_999776lp_LBE397_7000175.png"  Content-Type: application/octet-stream     <IMAGE DATA>    --------------------------3df4e8eee91da308--
```

So, there are two files: event and image.

This is my code from controller:

```
public ActionResult NewEvent([FromForm]DataFromCameraModel @event, [FromForm]IFormFile image)
{
return Ok();
}

public class DataFromCameraModel
{
public int packetCounter {get;set;}
public string Datetime {get;set;}
public string plateText {get;set;}
}
```

In debug mode, I can see that only image file is found, but in @event model all values are null/0;

How to read datas from json "event" file?

Comment: Try and remove the `FromForm` from the `IFormFile` it shouldn't be required and might be causing the discrepancy

Comment: You can also achieve the requirement by implementing a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-model-binder-sample) to bind values to properties of `DataFromCameraModel` based on posted json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted file cannot be directly addressed as a model class in the method parameters, it can be accessed as another `IFormFile`

```
public ActionResult NewEvent([FromForm]IFromFile @event, [FromForm]IFormFile image)
{
    // parse JSON data from @event
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@event.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        var eventObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataFromCameraModel>(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }

    return Ok();
}
```